# Virtualenv - DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, homebrew, pipenv

I am using pipenv to install beautifulsoup, and for some reason I'm getting a deprecation warning. (For context, I used brew to install python, and pip3 to install pipenv):

```
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /Users/kylemart/Desktop/test/Pipfile
Using /usr/local/bin/python3.7m (3.7.0) to create virtualenv...
⠋Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3.7m
Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7'
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py:1041: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
New python executable in /Users/kylemart/.local/share/virtualenvs/test-F6PO10ji/bin/python3.7
Also creating executable in /Users/kylemart/.local/share/virtualenvs/test-F6PO10ji/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Setting project for test-F6PO10ji to /Users/kylemart/Desktop/test

Virtualenv location: /Users/kylemart/.local/share/virtualenvs/test-F6PO10ji
Installing beautifulsoup4...
Collecting beautifulsoup4
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/21/0a/47fdf541c97fd9b6a610cb5fd518175308a7cc60569962e776ac52420387/beautifulsoup4-4.6.3-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: beautifulsoup4
Successfully installed beautifulsoup4-4.6.3

Adding beautifulsoup4 to Pipfile's [packages]...
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (4df8f1)...
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 1/1 — 00:00:00
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue but I my case it was with sklearn Library and in order to fix the warning this is what I did (you can also do the same):

1. Open the file with editing privileges named `cloudpickle.py` which is present at this location `\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py`
2. replace `import imp` and 
   `from imp import find_module` with `import importlib` at the top of the file.
3. find function named `find_module` and replace the line 
   `file, path, description = find_module(path)` 
   with
   `file, path, description = importlib.utils.find_spec(path)`

So, in conclusion, you have to replace mention of `imp module` with `importlib` in the file which is throwing the error. In your case the file is present at `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py`

You can refer https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html 
and https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib for further info about the module in question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing this same issue. In my Linux machine i just remove the installed packages **numpy** and **pandas** and reinstall that. Finally my problem solved..

Try this..

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip uninstall numpy
pip install pandas
pip install numpy
```